# How update only one value inside field of table Sqlite when update from store my App Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I have an IOS app in Swift, let’s say version 1.0.0, and the sqlite scheme provides a table "Person" with the fields "name", "surname", "address" and "flag_first_use".

As soon as a user downloads the app, some screens are displayed and "flag_first_use" = true (the default is false).

I wish that when an old user updates the app to version 1.0.1 automatically they had "flag_first_use"= false.

How can i do it?

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Bad design solution I guess if this needs to be used for many versions, you should have a field that contain a version number so you could compare current version vs stored version.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of my problem is the creation of file migration. In this file i can manage the value of my attribute.

So in file migration1.0.0_to_1.0.1 i set that flag_first_use = false